# MySQL Query - Invalid use of group function when using CAST and SUM

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that's generating the "Invalid use of group function" error:

```
SELECT dac_name, unit_name, ptn, unit_type, monthly_recurring, directory_charges
FROM sprint WHERE date='$current_sprint_date' AND CAST( directory_charges AS DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) ) > SUM( CAST( directory_charges AS DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) ) * .01) ORDER BY CAST(directory_charges AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to SUM over one value - you probably would want GROUP BY something because at the moment it doesn't make sense. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to return rows where the directory_charges are greater than 1% of the sum of all of the directory_charges.

Comment: You can't use aggregate functions in `WHERE`.  Try using it in the `HAVING` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an aggregate function like `SUM()` in a WHERE clause. Aggregates are dependent on the rows that are selected, so using them while selecting rows doesn't make sense. You can use it in a `HAVING` clause, which performs a second filter after rows have been selected and processed:

```
SELECT dac_name, unit_name, ptn, unit_type, monthly_recurring, directory_charges
FROM sprint
WHERE date='$current_sprint_date'
HAVING CAST( directory_charges AS DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) ) > SUM( CAST( directory_charges AS DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) ) * .01)
ORDER BY CAST(directory_charges AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: That's no longer generating an error, thank you. However, it's returning 0 rows. Maybe my math is wrong...

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: Most of the columns have blank values for directory_charges, but sample values for the ones that do have values are '3.99', '17.05', etc. If I change the query and add directory_charges != '', it now returns just one row, which is the highest number. Still missing the rest. Weird.

Comment: What is `SUM(directory_charges)`?

Comment: 45.77. And SUM( CAST( directory_charges AS DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) ) * .01) returns 0.4577, which should be less than many of the directory_charges.

Comment: Please make a sqlfiddle and I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Seems to be the SUM() is causing it to return only one row. Supposedly GROUP BY will fix this but not sure where to put it in the query.

Comment: Figured it out, needed to add the GROUP BY clause right before the HAVING